# Were there any Senate hearings involved in ending WW I trench warfare?

Tags: world-war-one

I know that tanks becoming more reliable was a part of why trench warfare started to dissipate at the end of World War I. I want to know if there was much in the way of political commentary or public opinion concerning trench warfare.

Comment: Why would the Senate review military tactics? The Senate is not in the chain of command.

Comment: ok, got it Mark.  I guess my question is what led to the end of trench warfare? Were there political leaders that wanted to put an end to trench warfare tactics?

Comment: Trench Warfare wasn't a decision, it was a consequence. That's a big question, why did WWI devolve into trench warfare? Tanks weren't particularly decisive in WWI. They were slow, unreliable, blind, and there were never enough of them. What broke the stalemate was the new tactics the Germans used in the [1918 Spring Offensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Offensive), the exhaustion of the Central Powers, and the enormous fresh injection of manpower and resources the US brought in.

Comment: It is in the nature of politicians to have opinions about everything, but the constitution is clear that the Commander in Chief is an executive position; the Senate's only role in military affairs is to appropriate money.  @Schwern is a very educated military historian and his comment should probably be submitted as and answer.

Comment: If you're interested in WWI in detail, I'd suggest [The Great War](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheGreatWar) who are going through WWI week by week, as it happened 100 years ago. [Welcome To The Dirt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJV3ZGclI8o), [Trench Warfare In WWI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P92guhd7d-8), and [Tank Development In WWI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjj13U-j0_g) will get you started.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Aww, sucks. :) I'll write up an answer.

Comment: I guess i'll look for newspaper and/or editorials on what public opinion might have been.  I'm trying to write and find sources that will explain reasons behind ending trench warfare

Comment: Why do you believe that the answer is in public opinion and not military operations?  Is there a reason to assume that Generals and Colonels did not see that trench warfare was unproductive?

Comment: I see your point Mr. Wallace.  I'll look more towards what military leaders put in writing as to why they began to get away from trench warfare

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace: If the Generals &c had actually seen that trench warfare was unproductive, why did they go on doing it for so long?  The only explanations I can think of involve sheer stupidity on the part of the top brass (strongly supported by my own, much later, experience), or devolve into various conspiracy theories.

Comment: With the construction of the Maginot Line in the 1930's I'd say the French didn't think that trench warfare (or perhaps defensive warfare) was going out of style.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I meant to say "aww, shucks"! :)

Comment: @jamesqf There was *a lot* of sheer stupidity at the top. [The Great War did a Top 11 Stupid Moves of Early World War I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siY6C55ndI4). But also a fundamental misunderstanding, often willful, of how technology had changed warfare in a decade or two. Something to keep in mind, telephones, cameras, radio, and film were all pretty new and it was very easy to get a false picture of what was happening at the front unless you actually went there, and they didn't. These people were leading 10x the men they were used to in battles lasting months instead of days.

Comment: @Schwern: That's really my point.  Surely any halfway intelligent commander would have figured out from the casualty figures that sending men "over the top" did nothing but get them killed.  So why keep doing it, unless your purpose is actually to kill off a lot of your own people, make money for armaments makers. or something of that sort?

Comment: @jamesqf With a few exceptions, I've never gotten the impression the tactics had those sort of treasonous ulterior motives. Why they kept repeating the same failing tactics is a BIG question. You should ask it. Or watch [The Great War](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=siY6C55ndI4), they talk about it all the time.

Answer (score 7):

> *I know that tanks becoming more reliable was a part of why trench warfare started to dissipate at the end of World War I.*

That premise isn't correct. Tanks were a *part* of why World War *Two* didn't devolve into trench warfare again (despite many expecting it to), but a WWI tank was rather different.

Tanks were an *attempt* to break the stalemate of WWI, but for the most part failed. WWI tanks were intended to trundle across No Man's Land, immune to rifle and machine gun fire, and overrun the trenches allowing infantry to follow up. They lacked the mobility and reliability to do this effectively, most tanks broke down or bogged down, often before even reaching the battlefield. This problem still plagues tanks today. Their slow speed, typically a walking pace, and difficult steering made them easy targets for a calm artillery gunner. And their poor "armor", not real armor, but soft boiler plate, could be penetrated by even improvised weapons like a [reversed bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversed_bullet).

[David Fletcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Fletcher_(military_historian)), of the Bovington Tank Museum, [has a Tank Chat about the British Mark I tank](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a8Jq5lagUOw). While there were other tanks and improvements, his comments about the Mark I are generally applicable to WWI tanks. Another good resource is [The Great War](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUcyEsEjhPEDf69RRVhRh4A) and their special on [Tank Development In WWI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjj13U-j0_g).

More importantly they lacked the communications and tactics to coordinate with the infantry and artillery (aka ["combined arms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_arms)). WWI tanks, if they crossed the trenches, had a tendency to continue on alone, reaching the enemy rear area and then sort of milling about. Being basically blind, it was fairly easy to roll up an artillery piece and blast it.

And there simply weren't enough of them, working and in position, at any time to have a strategic effect.

> *I want to know if there was much in the way of political commentary or public opinion concerning trench warfare.*

I'm pretty sure nobody liked it, and everyone was finding a way to break the stalemate, but their total lack of experience with modern war meant that most of the ideas were utterly unrealistic. They probably made it worse by employing short sighted or impractical strategies. Everyone was looking for "the big push", some magic bullet to break the stalemate, rather than looking at the problem systemically.

Based on your comments it seems the premise is that trench warfare was some sort of choice...

> *I guess i'll look for newspaper and/or editorials on what public opinion might have been. I'm trying to write and find sources that will explain reasons behind ending trench warfare – robluke 9 mins ago*

Nobody planned trench warfare. WWI in the west was supposed to be a highly mobile war like the proceeding [Franco-Prussian War of 1870](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco-Prussian_War) was. The initial German attack went according to the [Schlieffen Plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlieffen_Plan), a giant right hook by the German army aimed at Paris that nearly worked. It was only when the attack ran out of steam that the armies began digging defensive trenches. [The Germans fell back along a ridge and everyone dug in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJV3ZGclI8o).

And they kept on digging. They typical way of dealing with a strong defensive line is to charge it, now futile with machine guns and rapid fire rifles, or outflank it, to get around the sides. As each side tried to outflank each other, they extended their trenches further and further and further until [they were literally racing each other north to the sea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B27f4tEROJU). The result was, very quickly, a contiguous line of defenses from the North Sea to Switzerland.

Both sides sought to break the stalemate with technology, and tactics, but mostly by opening up new fronts like [attempting to capture Constantinople by sea](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuqJ7R62X-E). These all failed.

What finally broke the stalemate was new ["Stormtrooper" tactics and training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormtrooper) first used en masse in the [1918 German Spring Offensive, the Kaiserschlacht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Offensive). Rather than trying to control large, unwieldy, overambicous attacks by hundreds of thousands of men, these centered around small, independent, heavily armed squads infiltrating the enemy positions and overwhelming them with speed, surprise, and heavy firepower. Submachine guns, grenades, pistols, and [brutal hand weapons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIGIBJeRfnQ) were the weapons of choice. The Allies had also improved their tactics. These basic tactics are still used today.

This nearly won the war for the Germans, but both sides were exhausted after years of taking millions of casualties. The Germans didn't have enough resources to follow up on their successes, and the Allied lines were being stiffened by fresh troops from the US.

Trench warfare ended, in large part, because the Allies won the war of attrition. The Germans no longer had the reserves to replace their casualties in the trenches, and they'd just used up their best troops in the Spring Offensive. Their tactical successes left them with longer lines to defend, and a million less men to defend them. While the Allies had fresh US troops to act as replacements. The German lines thinned and finally collapsed in a collection of battles known as [The Hundred Days Offensive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Days_Offensive).

Comment: Nice summary!  I'd add that after my own research, I think the practice of destroying one's own army in successive "big pushes" was largely a British achievement, to the point where the army was turned over so fast in personnel that it never really learned.  I see accounts of French soldiers making tactical advances across no-man's land in 1916, and Germans in early 1915. The British attempt to break the paradigm was the tank, but as you nicely summarize, it was hardly beyond experimental.  Tank theory and design would remain nebulous until the late 1930s, but the debate continues even today.